# Ubuntu Server 16.04 filesystem usage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, disk-usage

I have installed ubuntu server 16.04 as a webserver at work. I had initially allocated 100GB to it. For some reason, some of the space has been eaten up by tmpfs and I am not able to claim it back.

Here is what i get when I run `df -h`

```
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                  31G     0   31G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                6.2G  8.9M  6.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/filesystem--vg-root       36G   34G  238M 100% /
tmpfs                                 31G     0   31G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                 31G     0   31G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                            472M   57M  391M  13% /boot
tmpfs                                6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/1000
```

It appears that my `/` folder is full. Which is not supposed to be the case. The server has already used up the 36GB only. Please help someone.

Comment: If you're new to Linux it's best to let the installer partition for you.

Comment: True, will do that in future @Alxs. But now i need to resolve the mess that i have created. If you could assist, i would be very greatful.

Comment: Can you please add result of command `du -sh /*`

Comment: Your root filesystem is a logical volume so you can quite easily expand it by adding another partition to the volume group and growing the filesystem.  Do you have another disk with space attached?

Comment: I do not have another disk attached with space attached @Alxs .

Comment: When i run du -sh /*, it shows that /var used 27GB, which is expected since there are some files that my webserver has placed in there. The other files are just normal sizes. @RomeoNinov

Comment: Can you provide the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: @TomGeneric, please check with `du -sh /var/*` and drill down till you find the root cause :)

Comment: @Alxs  fdisk indicates that /dev/sda is 100GB, and /dev/mapper/thitoacademics--vg-root: 36.6 GiB and /dev/mapper/thitoacademics--vg-swap_1: 62.9 GiB

Comment: I beliver my problem is coming from the /dev/mapper/thitoacademics--vg-swap_1: 62.9 GiB. I dont know how i can reduce its size.

Comment: How much RAM does this system have btw?

Comment: @RomeoNinov this is what i get after recreating swap. <pre>sudo swapon --show
NAME      TYPE       SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/dm-1 partition 62.9G   0B   -1
/swapfile file         6G   0B   -2 </pre>

Comment: Check with `swap -l` what is activated now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As understand from the comments OP have very huge swap partition. Here is the procedure to shrink it to the reasonable size:

1. Disable swap: 
   `swapoff /dev/mapper/thitoacademics--vg-swap_1`
2. Change the swap LV to 4GB: 
   `lvreduce -L 4G /dev/mapper/thitoacademics--vg-swap_1`
3. Recreate new swap (just in case): 
   `mkswap /dev/mapper/thitoacademics--vg-swap_1`
4. Add new swap: 
   `swapon /dev/mapper/thitoacademics--vg-swap_1`

All those commands need to be executed as root

For moving the free diskspace to the other LV/filesystem you should follow those steps:

1. Extend the other filesystem:

`lvextend -L+4G /dev/mapper/filesystem--vg-root`

2. Extend the filesystem

`resize2fs /dev/mapper/filesystem--vg-root`

Again all those commands need to be executed as root